# Dúvida de listas python3 Conway Game of Life

Tags: python-3.x

Boa tarde a todos! 
Estou no momento trabalhando num diagrama, onde cada elemento é uma lista. 
Para a entrada da lista, fiz a seguinte linha de comandos:

```
diagrama_entrada=[]

x=True                                
while x:
    l=input()
    if not l.isdigit():
        lixta=l.split(" ")
        diagrama_entrada.append(lixta)
    else:       
    x=False
    for i in range(int(l)):
        num_sequencias=int(l)


num_colunas=len(diagrama_entrada[0][0])                         
num_linhas=len(diagrama_entrada)                #Linhas

print(diagrama_entrada)

for j in range(len(diagrama_entrada)):
    print(" ".join(diagrama_entrada[j]))
```

A entrada é do tipo indicado neste link http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~mc102/labs/roteiro-lab09.html:

Porém, quando tento analisar as listas individualmente, elas aparecem desse modo: 
    [['+-----+'], 
    ['|', '', '', '', '', '|'], 
    ['|', '', '@', '', '|'], 
    ['|', '@', '@', '|'], 
    ['|', '', '@', '', '|'], 
    ['|', '', '', '', '', '|'],
    ['+-----+']]

Ou seja, o programa está sumindo com alguns espaços vazios do diagrama, de modo que, percorrendo com um for a lista, dá erro.

Como poderia consertar isso?

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar:

```
lixta = list(l)
```

Ao invés de :

```
lixta=l.split(" ")
```